# Why my certificate is still not recognized by some hosts?

Tags: tls, certificates

My website certificate is not recognized by all hosts.
I already scanned here https://www.ssllabs.com/ssltest/analyze.html?d=eleicoesjustas.org.

Is that because of Java trust store?

Unfortunately some Android users are complaining about that and I still don't know how to solve it.

Comment: The trusted root CA list on Android depends on the used Android version and sinve about Android 6 users can not add trused root CA certificates. But you can do so for your app: using Android [Network Security Config](https://developer.android.com/training/articles/security-config#TrustingAdditionalCas) you can include the root CA file in your app and add it as trusted root CA certificate only for your app. That should work for Android 6+.

Answer (score 2):

Your certificate is trusted by Windows, MacOS, iOS, Android and Firefox. That means, the vast majority of *clients* will indeed trust your server's certificate.

Java, as a client, will not do so by default, as the root certificate `TrustCor RootCert CA-1` is not in the default Java trust store.

#### Is this an issue?

Most likely not. If the server's main function is to serve a website, then your visitors will not notice any issues.

However, if you use this server specifically to interact with a Java application, then you may run into issues. If this is not something you do, feel free to not care.

Comment: Yeah. Thanks. Unfortunately some Android users are complaining about that and I still don't know how to solve that.

Comment: Android should not be affected - at least according to the report. You can always try using a certificate by [Let's Encrypt](https://letsencrypt.org/).

Comment: Yeah, but before that I really need to understand the reason why. I don't like much Let's Encrypt's process. That's not very transparent in my perspective since the need me to install application on my side. That doesn't make any sense. Why wouldn't a CSR be enough for them?

Comment: @Maf: To encourage automation. Note that you *also* need an application to generate CSRs. I would give LE a shot, there's good reason everyone uses them

Comment: Why do you say everyone LE when no everyone uses LE? Generating a CSR is very straightforward. That's just lie creating a document with your information and signing it. Just that.

Comment: What do you think the ACME protocol does? You could use the RFC and play it by hand if you don't trust any of the open source tools that perform the validation.... And given what's just transpired (https://twitter.com/matthew_d_green/status/1589985955725062144?t=gVLK7By0BeBy4I14eWyckg&s=19) choosing TrustCor over LetsEncrypt for trust reasons is absolutely hilarious.